# How to change dtype & apply mathematical calculations in np.where?

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, numpy

I have dataframe like this

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['yy'] = [2012,2011,2010]
df['mm'] = ['10','','8']

    yy      mm
0   2012    10
1   2011    
2   2010    8
```

I want to multiply values in column 'mm' with 2. However all values on the column are string.
I tried it with np.where as follows:

```
df['X'] = np.where(df['mm']!='',df['mm'].astype(int) * 2,'')
```

However its not working & giving error as follows:
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''.
Its clear from the error that the first filter in the where doesnt work here & its applying df['mm'].astype(int) on all values hence failing for empty string value ''.

Can anyone please suggest a another way to achieve this ? I don't want to use for loop as y actual df is too big & for loop will take lot of time.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Each of the 3 arguments are evaluated before they are passed to `where`.  So indidually they shoild be valid.  Test if nesessary before hand. For `where(cond, a, b)`, `a` and `b` should have the same `dtype`

Answer (score 0):

It's better if you replace the empty strint with NaN first:

```
df['mm'] = df.mm.replace({'': np.nan}).fillna(0).astype(int) * 2
```